# How to append more than one array to formData()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react fro front end and express for backend. Also multer, which is a third party package to handle file inputs. Now what I want is that there should be an array of objects that I could append to formData and send it via axios. However I fail to do so. I wrote the following code:

```
 const handleSubmit = (id, e) => {
    //formdata object to be created
    e.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataFolder.length; i++) {
        formData.append('body[]', dataFolder[i])
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
        formData.append('image', imageArray[i])
    }
    addUpdateProduct(formData)
    handleClose()
}
```

addUpdateProduct(formData) is a redux action that then calls the backend route.

'DataFolder' here is an array of objects that has key value pairs such as:

```
 dataFolder = [ {name: 'BB cream', type: 'cream'},{name: 'Neomycin', type: 'ointment'}]
```

'imageArray'is also an array of images containing an array of files. When i console it in my express controller i get the following output:

[image]

The files get uploaded correctly in the files array but dataFolder does not show up the expected way. Any solutions?

Comment: Please include data as text, not as a picture of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the description of [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):

> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.

`{name: 'BB cream', type: 'cream'}` is an object, not a string or a blob. If you convert a plain object to a string you get `'[object Object]'` as you can see in the data received by the server.

You could encode it as JSON to make it a string.

Comment: But if I use this syntax then JSON.stringify(dataFolder[i]) then the whole thing becomes a string. How do I convert it back into an array of object because my db query expects an array not string

Comment: With JSON.parse.